# PHP Wiki Regex Scripts

Tags: php, regex, wiki, wiki-engine

Can you recommend any ready for use PHP scripts that replace certain strings with their html equivalents?

Comment: Also, you might want to clearify which [Lightweight Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) you are after